# How to get the text of an HTML tag with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, laravel, dom, get

I'm trying to get the text that contains certain tags within the `HTML` on a page, I'm using `simple_html_dom.php` that I thought was good for this. Without more I leave an example of my problem.

This is the function in php

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

function precioExito($url){
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    $posts = $html->find('p[class=price offer]');
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $resultado = str_replace ( ".0", '', $post);
        break;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

What I do is that I call this function if I do an echo to that value it shows me the value on the screen (View image)

[image: Click to see image]

But when that value that returns to me I send it to the BD, this is what saves me in the BD. (View image)

[image: Click to see image]

As you can see, it's bringing me the whole HTML tag and not just the value.

**QUESTION**

How can I get only the value of this tag in order to save it?

Comment: Go to mention link and try https://github.com/miclf/simple-html-dom/blob/master/example/example_basic_selector.php . You have to parse data attributewise. You have to mention it. If it will not working, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you are posting the whole html element..

what you need to do is parse its innerText

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $resultado = str_replace ( ".0", '', $post->innertext);
    break;
}
```